# HTML text jumps out of DIV block

Tags: html, css

I'm building a panel for a front end system, but I got an annoying problem.
I am not that good with CSS. This is what happens:

[image]

This is my HTML code:

```css
#main #myTopMenu #iconBar {
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: right;
}

#main #myTopMenu #iconBar a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 30px;
  color: white;
}

#main #myTopMenu #iconBar .optionsContainer {
  line-height: 55px;
}

#main #myTopMenu #iconBar .optionsContainer img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}

#main #myTopMenu #iconBar .valueWithOption {
  background-color: #59a632;
  height: 25px;
  width: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  margin-left: 27px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#main #myTopMenu #iconBar .valueWithOption span {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="iconBar">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="optionsContainer">
      <img src="images/icons/message.png">
      <div class="valueWithOption">
        <span>5</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="optionsContainer"><img src="images/icons/bell.png">
      <div class="valueWithOption"><span>5</span></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="optionsContainer"><img src="images/icons/settings.png"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Also do you guys have tips to make it so that the width of the green box expands so that the value in the green box always fits properly.

Comment: What is the problem? You showed what happens, but that isn't clear. We can assume, but we shouldn't have to. Make your problem clear and explain what you expect to happen.

Comment: I am sorry that I wasn't clear. I will try to be clear in the future. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some significant changes to your codes for expected results. See snippet

```css
 #iconBar {
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: right;
}

#iconBar a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 30px;
  color: white;
}


#iconBar .optionsContainer img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}

#iconBar .valueWithOption {
  background-color: #59a632;
padding: 5px;
  top: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
top: -10px;
display:inline-block
}

#iconBar .valueWithOption span {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<div id="iconBar">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="optionsContainer">
      <img src="images/icons/message.png">
      <div class="valueWithOption">
        <span>5</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="optionsContainer"><img src="images/icons/bell.png">
      <div class="valueWithOption"><span>500</span></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="optionsContainer"><img src="images/icons/settings.png"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This fixed my problem.

Comment: You should explain WHY your answer works. While your answer may fix his problem, it is not helpful to the OP or anyone else facing a similar issue. "Teach a man to fish" is the idea.